# How do I read a text file into a 2D vector?

Tags: c++, string, vector, char, 2d-vector

I have to read a text file which has rows and columns into a vector. The text file could be of any size.
One example of text file:

```
T,T,T,F,T
T,T,T,T,T
T,T,T,T,T
T,T,T,T,T
T,T,T,T,T
T,T,T,T,T
T,T,T,T,T
```

Now, how do I upload this text file on to a 2D vector?

so far, I know I have to use a vector of vectors (2d vector) and so I initialized it like this:

```
vector<vector<char> > forest;
```

I don't know how to move forward from here. I would assume I must use a nested for loop but I don't have much practice with 2d vectors.

I also was thinking about using `getline` and reading each line as a string or using the `.get` function and treat each character as a char within a `while` loop?

Comment: You can use getline and decode the string which you get from heroine function into vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `getline` to read the file line by line into strings. For each string you read, iterate over its characters to build row vectors to populate your forest:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::string line;
    std::ifstream infile("file.txt");
    std::vector<std::vector<char> > forest;

    while (std::getline(infile, line)) {
        std::vector<char> row;

        for (char &c : line) {
            if (c != ',') {
                row.push_back(c);
            }
        }

        forest.push_back(row);
    }

    for (std::vector<char> &row : forest) {
        for (char &c : row) {
            std::cout << c << ' ';
        }

        std::cout << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
T T T F T
T T T T T
T T T T T
T T T T T
T T T T T
T T T T T
T T T T T
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve programming problems such as this one, an effective approach is to decompose it into smaller problems and write functions to solve each one.

In this particular question, we might consider breaking the problem down as follows

1. Read the contents of a file, line by line.
2. Break up each line by some delimiter, in this particular case, the `,` character.
3. Store this result in the output data structure, i.e., `std::vector<std::vector<char>>`.

We can write a function to solve problem 1, rather simply in C++, using `ifstream` and `getline`, i.e.,

```
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

std::vector<std::vector<char>> read_char_matrix(std::string const &filename) {
    std::ifstream infile(filename);

    for (std::string line; std::getline(infile, line); ) {
        // Add stuff into a matrix
    }

    // Return the matrix
}
```

So, with a solution given to reading the contents of a file, we might now consider problem 2. Taking a brief moment to understand that problem 2 is, in fact, an independent problem, which simply requires breaking up a comma-separated string. Splitting a string by some delimiter can be achieved with an `istringstream`. We can write a separate function to achieve this, as follows

```
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>

std::vector<char> split_on(std::string const &str, char delimiter) {
    std::istringstream iss(str);
    std::vector<char> split_str;

    for (char c; iss >> c; ) {
        split_str.emplace_back(c);

        // Ignore delimiters
        if (iss.peek() == delimiter)
            iss.ignore();
    }

    return split_str;
}
```

Finally, we can bring this together into the following solution

```
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::vector<char> split_on(std::string const &str, char delimiter) {
    std::istringstream iss(str);
    std::vector<char> split_str;

    for (char c; iss >> c; ) {
        split_str.emplace_back(c);

        // Ignore delimiters
        if (iss.peek() == delimiter)
            iss.ignore();
    }

    return split_str;
}

std::vector<std::vector<char>> read_char_matrix(std::string const &filename) {
    std::ifstream infile(filename);
    std::vector<std::vector<char>> matrix;

    for (std::string line; std::getline(infile, line); ) {
        matrix.emplace_back(split_on(line, ','));
    }

    return matrix;
}
```

The function `read_char_matrix` can then be called with the filename and will return the intended matrix in a `std::vector<std::vector<char>>`.

Comment: it is not a good idea to solve the problem for him, if it is homework, he will just copy your answer and moves on to the next exercise without learning a thing.